# Mongodb Aggregation and Group By query

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have set of baskets stored in mongodb like:

```
/* 47 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("535ff14c2e441acf44708ec7"),
    "tip" : "0",
    "basketTransactionCash" : "2204",
    "basketTransactionCard" : "0",
    "completed" : ISODate("2014-04-07T14:35:17.000Z"),
    "consumerId" : null,
    "storeId" : 1,
    "basketId" : 210048,
    "basketProduct" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("535feffa2e441acf446facb7"),
            "name" : "Vanilla Spice Hot Chocolate",
            "productId" : 23,
            "basketProductInstanceId" : 838392,
            "quantity" : 1,
            "productModifiedPrice" : null,
            "productInstancePrice" : "633",
            "vatPercentage" : "0.2"
        }
    ],
    "created" : ISODate("2014-04-07T14:35:42.000Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 48 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("535ff14c2e441acf44708ede"),
    "tip" : "0",
    "basketTransactionCash" : "230",
    "basketTransactionCard" : "0",
    "completed" : ISODate("2014-04-07T14:41:51.000Z"),
    "consumerId" : 1,
    "storeId" : 1,
    "basketId" : 210072,
    "basketProduct" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("535feffa2e441acf446facf3"),
            "name" : "Melon",
            "productId" : 4544,
            "basketProductInstanceId" : 838430,
            "quantity" : 1,
            "productModifiedPrice" : null,
            "productInstancePrice" : "200",
            "vatPercentage" : "0"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("535feffa2e441acf446facf4"),
            "name" : "30p",
            "productId" : 8496,
            "basketProductInstanceId" : 838431,
            "quantity" : 1,
            "productModifiedPrice" : null,
            "productInstancePrice" : "30",
            "vatPercentage" : "0"
        }
    ],
    "created" : ISODate("2014-04-07T14:42:16.000Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}

/* 49 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("535ff14c2e441acf44708ee2"),
    "tip" : "0",
    "basketTransactionCash" : "2204",
    "basketTransactionCard" : "0",
    "completed" : ISODate("2014-04-07T14:41:54.000Z"),
    "consumerId" : 2,
    "storeId" : 1,
    "basketId" : 210076,
    "basketProduct" : [ 

        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("535feffb2e441acf446fad02"),
            "name" : "Creamy Natural Yoghurt",
            "productId" : 69,
            "basketProductInstanceId" : 839800,
            "quantity" : 1,
            "productModifiedPrice" : null,
            "productInstancePrice" : "911.7",
            "vatPercentage" : "0.2"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("535feffb2e441acf446fad03"),
            "name" : "Melon",
            "productId" : 4544,
            "basketProductInstanceId" : 839801,
            "quantity" : 1,
            "productModifiedPrice" : null,
            "productInstancePrice" : "200",
            "vatPercentage" : "0"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("535feffb2e441acf446fad04"),
            "name" : "30p",
            "productId" : 8496,
            "basketProductInstanceId" : 839802,
            "quantity" : 1,
            "productModifiedPrice" : null,
            "productInstancePrice" : "30",
            "vatPercentage" : "0"
        }
    ],
    "created" : ISODate("2014-04-07T14:43:00.000Z"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Could I have this grouped by completed by hourly? So the end result should be something similar to the below

```
{
        "totalTip" : "0",
        "basketTransactionCashTotal" : "4638",
        "basketTransactionCardTotal" : "0",
        "completed" : "2014-04-07 14",
        "consumerIds" : [null, 1, 2],
        "storeId" : 1,
        "basketIds" : [210048, 210072, 210076]
        "basketProduct" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("535feffa2e441acf446facf3"),
                "name" : "Melon",
                "productId" : 4544,
                "basketProductInstanceId" : 838430,
                "quantity" : 1,
                "productModifiedPrice" : null,
                "productInstancePrice" : "200",
                "vatPercentage" : "0"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("535feffa2e441acf446facf4"),
                "name" : "30p",
                "productId" : 8496,
                "basketProductInstanceId" : 838431,
                "quantity" : 1,
                "productModifiedPrice" : null,
                "productInstancePrice" : "30",
                "vatPercentage" : "0"
            },
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("535feffb2e441acf446fad02"),
                "name" : "Creamy Natural Yoghurt",
                "productId" : 69,
                "basketProductInstanceId" : 839800,
                "quantity" : 1,
                "productModifiedPrice" : null,
                "productInstancePrice" : "911.7",
                "vatPercentage" : "0.2"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("535feffb2e441acf446fad03"),
                "name" : "Melon",
                "productId" : 4544,
                "basketProductInstanceId" : 839801,
                "quantity" : 1,
                "productModifiedPrice" : null,
                "productInstancePrice" : "200",
                "vatPercentage" : "0"
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("535feffb2e441acf446fad04"),
                "name" : "30p",
                "productId" : 8496,
                "basketProductInstanceId" : 839802,
                "quantity" : 1,
                "productModifiedPrice" : null,
                "productInstancePrice" : "30",
                "vatPercentage" : "0"
            },
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("535feffa2e441acf446facb7"),
                "name" : "Vanilla Spice Hot Chocolate",
                "productId" : 23,
                "basketProductInstanceId" : 838392,
                "quantity" : 1,
                "productModifiedPrice" : null,
                "productInstancePrice" : "633",
                "vatPercentage" : "0.2"
            }
        ]
    }
```

Could anyone help me understand this for mongoose in nodejs please?

Comment: Why do you have the fields `tip`, `basketTransactionCash` and `basketTransactionCard` as Strings?  Unless they are numeric, you cannot perform arithmetic operations using aggregation framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, the fields `tip`, `basketTransactionCash` and `basketTransactionCard` **need to be converted to numeric type** for you to perform any arithmetic operations.  You can look at [`this question`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973095/mongodb-how-to-change-the-type-of-a-field) for an approach to update all documents with the right data type.

Once the data type is taken care of, you can use the [`aggregation framework`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) to get close to what you want.  The [`date aggregation operators`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/) provide a way to group by the hour.  Sample query is below:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
{
    "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "year": {"$year": "$completed"},
            "month": {"$month": "$completed"},
            "day": {"$dayOfMonth": "$completed"},
            "hour": {"$hour": "$completed"}
        },
        "totalTip": {
            "$sum": "$tip"
        },
        "basketTransactionCashTotal": {
            "$sum": "$basketTransactionCash"
        },
        "basketTransactionCardTotal": {
            "$sum": "$basketTransactionCard"
        },
        "consumerIds": {
            "$push": "$consumerId"
        },
        "storeId": {
            "$addToSet": "$storeId"
        },
        "basketIds": {
            "$push": "$basketId"
        },
        "basketProducts": {
            "$push": "$basketProduct"
        }
    }
}
])
```

I would suggest you to read up on aggregation and play around with it a little bit as it's a quite powerful tool.

**NOTE:** Unless the data types are updated, you'll get **0** for `totalTip`, `basketTransactionCashTotal` and `basketTransactionCardTotal`

Comment: Thank you Anand, I will try this now and post the seconds it take to execute the query.

Comment: Just have a look at my answer too and suggest any improvement. Thank you so much

Comment: If you can get the results you want using aggregation, it will most certainly perform much better than map-reduce.  Take a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13908438/is-mongodb-aggregation-framework-faster-than-map-reduce)

Comment: Thank you Anand. I will take yours as answer.