# Best way to return documents that include a count of an internal collection?

Tags: mongodb

Say I have a collection with documents like the following:

```
{
   title: "First",
   sub_items: ['test', 'another test', 'whatever]
},
{
   title: "Second",
   sub_items: ['something', 'something else']
}
```

And I would like to get output like below:

```
{"First", 3},
{"Second, 2}
```

What is the best way to do this?  I have implemented it using the `map` function like below:

```
db.coll.find().map(
   function(item)
   {
      return {title: item.title, count: item.sub_items.length};
   }
);
```

When attempting to get the above results, would I be better off from a performance perspective to try and use something like [aggregate](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/aggregation/) or [mapReduce](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/map-reduce/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using **MongoDB 2.6 or later**, you can use the [`$size`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) aggregation operator to get results close to what you want.  From the documentation for `$size`:

> Counts and returns the total the number of items in an array.

Below is an untested example:

```js
db.coll.aggregate([
    {"$project" : {"title" : 1, "count" : {"$size":"$sub_items"}}}
])
```

Comment: Nice, that definitely looks simpler.  Do you know how it would compare performance wise?

Comment: Using the aggregation framework is most certainly multiple times faster than map-reduce.  The accepted answer for [`this question`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13908438/is-mongodb-aggregation-framework-faster-than-map-reduce) should give you an idea.